# Aligning a stacked barchart to the bottom of the chart

Tags: d3.js

Thanks in advance for any help.

I'm new to D3 and javascript as a whole. I've been pretty stuck on this for a while now even searching through other similar posts.

I'd like to flip my stacked bar chart appropriately so that it aligns to the bottom of the SVG.

When I do try it the way I think it should be done, I get a "invalid negative value for '' message.

```
var dataset = [
    [
      { x: 0, y: 5 },
      { x: 1, y: 4 },
      { x: 2, y: 2 },
      { x: 3, y: 7 },
      { x: 4, y: 23 }
    ],
    [
      { x: 0, y: 10 },
      { x: 1, y: 12 },
      { x: 2, y: 19 },
      { x: 3, y: 23 },
      { x: 4, y: 17 }
    ],
    [
      { x: 0, y: 22 },
      { x: 1, y: 28 },
      { x: 2, y: 32 },
      { x: 3, y: 35 },
      { x: 4, y: 43 }
    ]
  ];

  //Width and Height
var w = 500;
    h = 300;


  //Create SVG canvas
  var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
            .attr('width', w)
            .attr('height', h);

  //Set up Stack
var stack = d3.layout.stack();

  //Stack dataset 
    stack(dataset);

  //Create scales
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(d3.range(dataset[0].length))
            .rangeRoundBands([0,w], 0.05);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0,       
              d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
                return d3.max(d, function(d) {
                  return d.y0 + d.y;
                });
              })
            ])
            .range([0, h]);

  //Create colors for scale 
var colors = d3.scale.category10();

  //Create a Group for each row of data
var groups = svg.selectAll('g')
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()  //only creates placeholder
            .append('g')  //creates group
            .style('fill', function(d, i) {
              return colors(i);
            });

  //Add a rectangle for each datavalue 
      var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return xScale(i);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.y0 + d.y); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return yScale(d.y0) - yScale(d.y0 + d.y); })
    .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand());
```

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/)?

Comment: I hadn't seen that one, but have seen others. I understand in a simple bar chart taking the height of the svg and subtracting out the value of the data, but when there are multiple values in a stacked chart I'm a bit confused. I don't believe it's as simple as taking the height less one value, or at least I don't think so.

Comment: There are many many examples for normal and stacked bar charts in D3 that you can use as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the way height is getting calculated for each bar. See [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/heCrDUSr93OTw3m4576J?p=preview). Is this something you were looking for. May be you can use height (h) variable for your calculations.  I changed y parameters like below.

```
 //Add a rectangle for each datavalue 
var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return xScale(i);
  })
  /*  .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.y0 + d.y); })
   .attr("height", function(d) { return yScale(d.y0) - yScale(d.y0 + d.y); })

            .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.y0 ); })
   .attr("height", function(d) { return yScale(d.y0 + d.y);})
   */

.attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.y0 + d.y);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return h - yScale(d.y0 + d.y);
  })
  .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand());
```